# repeatable background image using bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, twitter-bootstrap-3, repeat

i have little issue with repeating background image using bootstrap framework, but i'm quite beginner. I tried many ways already and nothing works.
Can u help me with that please ? I've tried for example that :

```
<style>
 html, body {
 background: url("img/bg-pattern.png") repeat;} 
</style>
```

Comment: Is `img/bg-pattern.png` a valid path?

Comment: Does your image show at least once?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. My only guess is that your path isn't valid. http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/d9qFL/

Comment: i solved it, sorry that path wasn't really valid,but thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your path is probably incorrect. As far as I can see, bootstrap has a different folder structure than what your code suggests. Try this:

```
 body {
     margin: 0;
     background: url("../img/bg-pattern.png") repeat;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm unable to reproduce your issue [on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/d9qFL/). For this reason I can only presume your image path is invalid.

In specifying `img/bg-pattern.png`, you're pointing to the `bg-pattern.png` file contained within the `img` folder contained within the same folder as your CSS. This assumes a folder structure of:

```js
img
myHtml.html // Where your style element is included
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your **"img/bg-pattern.png"** is present in the same folder where your file is present
else give the *absolute path of the image*.

Answer (score 0):

Try using FireBug, maybe you'll see that the `<body>` tag is much smaller ( in height ) than you think.

I've moved my `background: ...` from the `<body>` tag to the actual `<div>` that contains the entire content ( which grow dynamically vs the `<body>` ) and the background is repeatable there ...